# Create another instance of a div

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So if the user clicks the text 'Add new entry' the div called "gamesrepeat" is created again, so the user can add multiple answers for the same question, is this possible?

the code I have is :

```
 <div id="games">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="Video Games"><b>Games</b>     </asp:Literal>

        <div id="gamesrepeat">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Video game name?</td>
                    <td>console for game?</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine">  </asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>

        <div id="addnew">

            Add new entry</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried..? did you even try a [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+dynamically+add+a+text+box+on+button+click&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=74GyU5CZMIfV8geRxYGwDg&gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+dynamically+add+copy+of+a+div+on+button+click&rls=en&safe=active)..?

Comment: You've tagged this as `asp.net-mvc` while you're clearly using asp controls, indicating you're using `webforms`.

Comment: using asp view in mvc project

Comment: That doesn't work for me